# GWT + Spring + No bean named 'dispatch' is defined

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, smartgwt, gwtp

while trying to use spring dependency injection instead of **guice**, getting below error

No bean named **'dispatch'** is defined

```
[WARN] /dispatch/
org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'dispatch' is defined
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanDefinition(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:527)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getMergedLocalBeanDefinition(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1083)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:274)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1079)
    at org.springframework.web.context.support.HttpRequestHandlerServlet.init(HttpRequestHandlerServlet.java:57)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:212)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.initServlet(ServletHolder.java:433)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.getServlet(ServletHolder.java:342)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:463)
```

Could you please help on this.

### web.xml content is as below

```
<context-param>
<param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
<param-value>classpath*:META-INF/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
</context-param>



<listener>
<listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>


<servlet>
<servlet-name>dispatch</servlet-name>
<servlet-class>org.springframework.web.context.support.HttpRequestHandlerServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>dispatch</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>/dispatch/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

---

And SeverModule class is

```
package com.khush.util.server.spring;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Import;

import com.gwtplatform.dispatch.server.actionvalidator.ActionValidator;
import com.gwtplatform.dispatch.server.spring.HandlerModule;
import com.gwtplatform.dispatch.server.spring.actionvalidator.DefaultActionValidator;
import com.gwtplatform.dispatch.server.spring.configuration.DefaultModule;
import com.khush.util.shared.action.RetrieveAccountsAction;

@Configuration
@Import(DefaultModule.class)
public class ServerModule extends HandlerModule {

  public ServerModule() {
  }

  @Bean
  public RetrieveAccountsHandler getRetrieveAccountsHandler() {
    return new RetrieveAccountsHandler();
  }

  @Bean
  public ActionValidator getDefaultActionValidator() {
    return new DefaultActionValidator();
  }

  protected void configureHandlers() {
      bindHandler(RetrieveAccountsAction.class, RetrieveAccountsHandler.class);
  }
}
```

Regards.

Comment: You will need to post more information if you want others to help you. For example, XML configuration files or code snippets.

Comment: Hi Duncan, please find below code and config files -

Comment: How did you resolve this issue? I am having the same problem.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17607570/gwtp-dispatch-spring-issue-no-bean-named-dispatch-is-defined

Answer (score 0):

Can you paste in here the content of your applicationContext.xml. I think you forgot to add the tag :

```
<context:component-scan base-package="package to scan..."/>
```

Without this tag the Spring can't detect Beans outside the XML file.

Comment: thanks imrabti, above tag was there. just removed and added dispatcher servlet from web.xml and rebuilt and it worked fine.